# Postgresql and UTF8 to Latin1 conversion?

Tags: postgresql, bytea

We have a Postgresql database where the data is in Latin1. Apparently someone loaded some UTF8 encoded data into it since when I select data from some of the columns, I get stuff like:

```
SELECT symptoms from client
- -
"huvudvÃ¤rke"
- -
```

where "Ã¤" should be "ä". I could handle it with replace, ie.:

```
UPDATE client SET symptoms=replace(symptoms, 'Ã¤', 'ä');
```

I tried a couple of solutions I found, like using `convert` and `convert_to` but that leaves the data looking like `"huvudv\303\244rke"`.

Is there an existing solution to my problem?

EDIT:

```
SELECT symptoms, symptoms::bytea from client
- -
"huvudvÃ¤rke";"huvudv\303\203\302\244rke" 
- -
```

After the UPDATE above, query with symptoms::bytea outputs:

```
SELECT symptoms, symptoms::bytea from client
- -
"huvudvärke";"huvudv\303\244rke" 
- -
```

EDIT2:

```
select version();
"PostgreSQL 9.2.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit"

show client_encoding; --I'm using pgAdmin III 1.18.1
"UNICODE"

show server_encoding;
"UTF8"

SELECT symptoms, convert(convert_to(symptoms, 'utf-8'), 'latin-1', 'utf-8')::text from client;
"huvudvÃ¤rke","huvudv\303\203\302\203\303\202\302\244rke"
```

Comment: What're the actual bytes from the string? Show `symptoms::bytea` please.

Comment: Updated the requested info to the original question.

Comment: Ah, you're also on an old PostgreSQL version, since `bytea_output` seems to be set to `escape` not the new `hex` format. Please always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions.

Comment: Show `SHOW client_encoding;` from the client, and `SHOW server_encoding;`, also `SELECT version()` and from your terminal run the `locale` command please.

Comment: I updated the question regarding your request. Sorry for the lack of them.

Comment: OK, so you're talking in utf-8 to a utf-8 DB, via PgAdmin-III. There's nothing visibly wrong there. (There are known issues with the command line `psql` tool and encodings on Windows, but you're not using it). So the real mystery is how the mangled data got there in the first place. I'd be suspicious of whatever your regular application that's using the database is - it sounds like you thought the DB was latin-1, but it isn't, and if the app is trying to treat utf-8 as latin-1 that'd explain these issues.

Comment: The DB (apparently) is in UTF8 (per server_encoding) and usually SELECTs return 'ä' etc. fine. Apparently someone has loaded data into the DB stating that the UTF8 encoded file is Latin1 and we ended up with crappy data-this is how I figure it. I've gotten a lot of knowledge transfer from you on the encoding issue which hasn't been that clear to me, thank you. The original question still is if there is a correct and quick way to fix the broken data?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like whatever client you are using is confused about the text encoding; it's sending utf-8 bytes as if they were latin-1, probably.

Check:

- `SHOW client_encoding;`
- `SHOW server_encoding;`
- `locale` command in your terminal, if using `psql`

Your `update` is substituting the octal bytes `\303\244` which are the utf-8 encoding for "ä" (U+00E4). You're not substituting latin-1 encoded data where you think you are.

Observe:

```
regress=> SELECT convert_from(BYTEA 'huvudv\303\244rke', 'latin-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 huvudvÃ¤rke
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT convert_from(BYTEA 'huvudv\303\244rke', 'utf-8');
 convert_from 
--------------
 huvudvärke
(1 row)
```

Not only that, but your `replace` could only have matched in the first place if the replace target was the *utf-8 encoded* byte sequence for `Ã¤` interpreted as latin-1, i.e. `\303\203\302\244`.

It's hard to be more specific without details about the Pg version, the client being used, etc, but the root cause is clearly your client doing something totally borked with encodings on I/O.

Your original text is totally mangled, it's not valid in UTF-8 or latin-1. It looks like someone's taken some UTF-8 data, decoded it as latin-1, and then encoded it as utf-8 again.

Yep, sure enough:

```
regress=> SELECT convert(convert_to('huvudvärke', 'utf-8'), 'latin-1', 'utf-8');
          convert          
---------------------------
 huvudv\303\203\302\244rke
(1 row)
```

there's your explanation.

I'd say you probably have a bunch of mis-encoded data in the DB already, and you noticed this one because it got mangled *twice*. You're probably doing something like routinely jamming utf-8 bytes into latin-1 encoded fields, but you usually get away with it because you decode them as utf-8 again - and this time you did something different.

If you want to get from your mangled text to the original, you simply have to reverse the incorrect encoding process. Decode the utf-8 and output latin-1, then re-interpet the latin-1 as utf-8 and decode again, e.g:

```
regress=> SELECT  convert_from(convert(BYTEA 'huvudv\303\203\302\244rke', 'utf-8', 'latin-1'), 'utf-8');
 convert_from 
--------------
 huvudvärke
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yeah, this used to be (or maybe still is) a problem for Hungarian texts.  For a time, you could see many websites with the same misinterpreted characters (well, the browsers were also confused...)  Once I could relatively easily read all these Ã¤ and similar vowels :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to dest_encoding. The original encoding is specified by src_encoding. The string must be valid in this encoding. Conversions can be defined by CREATE CONVERSION. Also there are some predefined conversions. See Table 9-7 for available conversions.

See  [Other String Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
convert(string bytea, src_encoding name, dest_encoding name)
convert_to(text_in_database,'LATIN1')
```

Comment: It did not work, like I mentioned in my original question. 'Ã¤' only converts to '\303\244'.

Comment: Good try, but you should *actually test the answer*. You'll find that the text provided is not valid latin-1 or utf-8, per my answer.

Comment: I did. The test was included in my original question.